# Taskmanager fails to connect to Jobmanager [Could not find any IPv4 address that is not loopback or link-local. Using localhost address.]

Tags: networking, apache-flink

We were previously using RHEL for our Flink machines. I'm currently working on moving them over to Ubuntu. When I start the task manager, it fails to connect to the job manager with the following message -

```
2020-01-16 10:54:42,777 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.util.LeaderRetrievalUtils            - Trying to select the network interface and address to use by connecting to the leading JobManager.
2020-01-16 10:54:42,778 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.util.LeaderRetrievalUtils            - TaskManager will try to connect for 10000 milliseconds before falling back to heuristics
2020-01-16 10:54:52,780 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.net.ConnectionUtils                  - Could not find any IPv4 address that is not loopback or link-local. Using localhost address.
```

The network interface on the machine looks like this -

```
ens5: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9001
        inet 10.16.75.30  netmask 255.255.255.128  broadcast 10.16.75.127
        ether 02:f1:8b:34:75:51  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 69370  bytes 80369110 (80.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 28787  bytes 2898540 (2.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 9562  bytes 1596138 (1.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9562  bytes 1596138 (1.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Note: On RHEL, the primary network interface was eth0. Could this be the issue?

Here's the full task manager log - https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vgh96FHzRq/

Comment: Could you share your config files used on job and task managers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the parameter `high-availability.cluster-id`. It was different on the task manager and the job manager. Updating it solved the issue.